# Resource describing D&D 4e's World Records

Tags: dnd-4e, online-resources

There is a well known topic from the times of D&D 3.5 that listed the world records for some stats, like most attacks per round, highest stat value, and so on. One of such topics is [this one](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=11680.0).

My question is, anyone know of a similar topic on D&D 4e? Something like absolute highest attack value, AC, defenses, bonus to saving throws, etc...

Comment: As a request for an existing, external resource, this is a valid question, as opposed for a request to create such a resource.

Comment: Because 4e made it a lot harder to push those numbers up to absurd heights than 3.X did, it may be that no such resource exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The old 4e CharOp boards on WotC forums had a DPR maximization thread based on maximizing damage/kills per round and compiling builds that did so. Since then, those boards have been deleted/removed, but here's a WayBack Machine link for you:
https://web.archive.org/web/20141112071821/http://community.wizards.com:80/content/forum-topic/3314581

And if you're looking for more high-powered builds or more 4e optimization in general, an old forum user has compiled a bunch of the old threads here: http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?472893-4E-Character-Optimization-WOTC-rescue-Handbook-Guide

Answer (score -3):

No such resource is findable. The OP should make it if he wants it--but as noted by Obivious Sage above, it's probably not going to be very interesting.

Note: D&D 4E reduced the ability to stack like this explicitely because of the ridiculous stacking that 3 and 3.5 allowed.